# Element order in the group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been reading some solution of a problem from abstract algebra and it says 'Take the maximum $n > 0$ of $\{v_2(|g|) : g \in G\}$, where G is group'. Does $v_2(|g|)$ means something? Because it is first mention at that point and I can't figure out what it means.

Comment: Are you following a book? A reference might be handy in providing you with an answer, as not every author uses the same notations.

Comment: Maybe this is the [2-valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_%28algebra%29#.CF.80-adic_valuation) of the order of $g$ ?

Comment: It's a Problem 2 on a page 6: http://vjimc.osu.cz/hist/j16solutions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In that context, the number $v_2(|g|)$ denotes the [$2$-valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_%28algebra%29#.CF.80-adic_valuation) of the order of $g$, i.e. the greatest $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $2^n$ divides the order of $g$.